# Whats the use of mapping @requestMapping onto an entire class?

Tags: spring-mvc

This is an extremely basic question about spring MVC i have seen a few examples where the @RequestMapping sits above the class name of a Controller :

```
@RequestMapping    
public class somethingController {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I understan the use of RequestMapping when it comes to methods but i haven't been able to understand the use of mapping it onto an entire  class. What is it used for?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It allows mapping all the methods to a URL, or a URL prefix, or other restrictions. Further restrictions (like POST/GET, or URL suffix, etc.) can then be defined by a RequestMapping annotation on the methods. These method-level restrictions will either complement or override the restrictions placed on the type-level annotation.

The attributes that can be used at class or method or both levels, and how they behave, are specified in [the javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html).

For example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", produces = "test/html")
public class SomeController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String method1() {
        ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String method1() {
        ...
    }
}
```

In this example, both methods are mapped on /foo and produce HTML, but the first one is called when the HTTP method is GET, whereas the second one is called when the HTTP method is POST.

Comment: that clarifies a lot for me, but following the topic, what would be the address to access a method that has its own value. for example adding a value to method1 at the RequestMapping  
@RequestMapping(value ="new",method=RequestMethod.GET)

Thanks for the preview answer also

Comment: If you annotate method1 with `RequestMapping(value = "/new")`, the URL for the method will be `/foo/new`. This is described in http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping